# On Screen Keyboard pops up at login Windows 7

Tags: windows, virtual-keyboard

A few weeks ago, I had to turn on the on screen keyboard (I did so through the ease of access menu at the login screen) as my keyboard was broken. It has been fixed since then, and when I turned it off a few weeks ago, the keyboard still shows up after I login when my desktop is loading. It closes once I press the close button, but I do not want it to show up at login. It is shown as disabled in the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Open the Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard page by clicking
>   the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel,
>   clicking Ease of Access, clicking Ease of Access Center, and then
>   clicking Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard.
>
> ```
> Clear the Use On-Screen Keyboard check box.
> ```

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/prevent-ease-of-access-programs-from-starting-automatically)